# Combo box drop down method in vba calling change method again and again

Tags: excel, vba

Part 1: A combo box in sheet1 to dynamically list unique values from a column in sheet2 put it in the drop down list

Part 2: Display the related entries of sheet2 in sheet1 based on the combo box selection.

I have done the part 1 in a method call fillCombo and have called it under ComboBox1_DropButtonClick() and part 2 under the method ComboBox1_Change()

First time when i click dropdown arrow of combo box it lists the unique entries and on making the selection in it, the related entries are displayed in sheet1 and everything is fine.

During the next selection of dropdown arrow it goes to ComboBox1_DropButtonclick() method then ComboBox1_change() method, ComboBox1_change() method without the dropdown list appearing and me selecting

So it works correctly only in the first instance.

Can you please correct the error.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim sht2, sht1, a As Long, X As Long, i As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    
    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    a = sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    X = 8
    
    
    Lastrow = sht1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    sht1.Range("G8:J" & Lastrow).Clear
    
    For i = 2 To a
    
         If sht2.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Payments" Then
              sht2.Cells(i, "C").Resize(1, 4).Copy sht1.Cells(X, "G")
              X = X + 1
         End If
    
    Next
     
    sht1.Select
    sht1.Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
Call fillCombo
End Sub

Sub fillCombo()

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Group = 3
firstTime = True
strValue = Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value

'last row
wsLR = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'loop thru rows
For l = 2 To wsLR
     If ws2.Cells(l, Group) <> "" And (InStr(uE, "|" & ws2.Cells(l, Group) & "|") = 0) Then
          If firstTime = True Then
             firstTime = False
             uE = "|" & uE & ws2.Cells(l, Group) & "|"
          Else
             uE = uE & ws2.Cells(l, Group) & "|"

          End If
      End If
Next l

dropValues = Split(uE, "|")

Sheet1.ComboBox1.Clear


For Each cell In dropValues
 If cell <> "" Then
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem cell
 End If
 
Next cell
Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value = strValue

End Sub
```

Comment: First, please [use `Option Explicit`](http://www.riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/3554/always-use--option-explicit-). Also, your variable `uE` is not initialized (or declared) the first time through the loop in `fillCombo`.